# Design of a Frequency Mixer

Tags: frequency, jfet, mixer

I am quite new to this subject. I want to design a frequency mixer to mix a carrier frequency of 100 MHz with a 20 kHz signal. I found the attached circuit. It seems quite a simple circuit to multiply both circuits obtained. However, I don't know and couldn't find how the resistor values could be found. Could someone please show me how to calculate their values please.

Moreover, what should the ratio of the transformer be please. Also, if there exists a simpler option on how to design a frequency mixer, it still works fine for me since I am willing to use any circuit.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Hey so maybe checking out this link could be of use - https://modernhamguy.com/active-mixers-in-rf-design/.

Although I feel using a Gilbert Cell Mixer is easier to deal with, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: @HyperBean It is truly a best option. But then again I don't know how to calculate the values of the components and i couldn't find anything helpful online

Comment: If you are mixing 100MHz and 20kHz the difference frequency will be at 100.02MHz and 99.998MHz. You will not be able to separate that from the 100MHz input with just an lC filter. You will need to use a more sophisticated mixer which suppresses both the RF and LO input (such as a Gilbert cell). Why do you want to do this? It is not a normal type of function.

Comment: I would suggest you buy a mixer. You can buy these devices: you can get them to mount on a printed circuit board, or with connectors. Check it out with Google.